# Удаление экземпляра класса

Tags: c++, классы, деструктор

В main.cpp создал экземпляр класса и динамически выделил под него память.

```
Rect*   pR = new Rect(1,2,1,2);
```

Создал деструктор

```
    Rect::~Rect()
    {
        delete pR;
    }
```

Выдаёт ошибку: " pR не определён в классе".

Объявил класс

```
    class Rect
    {
        int m_left, m_right, m_top, m_bottom;// объявили переменные
        
        public:
    
        //---------------------------------конструкторы----------------------------------------------
    
        Rect(); // явно переопределили дефолтовый конструктор без параметров
        
        Rect(int l, int r, int t, int b) // создали конструктор с параметрами
        {
            m_left = l;
            m_right = r;
            m_top = t;
            m_bottom = b;
        }
    
        Rect(const Rect& nov); // конструктор копирования
    
        ~ Rect(); // деструктор
    
        //--------------------------------методы------------------------------------------------------
    
        void Sec();                                     // проверка введенных данных
        void Print();                                   // печать
    
        int InflateRect(int a, int b, int c, int d);    // раздвигает стороны прямоугольника от центра
        int InflateRect(int z, int v);
        int InflateRect(int a);
    
        void SetAll(int a, int b, int c, int d);        // присваиваем значения переменным класса
        int GetAll();
        int GetRect_left();
        int GetRect_right();
        int GetRect_top();
        int GetRect_bottom();
    
        Rect BoundingRect(Rect r1, Rect r2);
```

Определил конструкторы и деструктор.

```
Rect::Rect()// конструктор без параметров
{
    m_left = 0;
    m_right = 0;
    m_top = 0;
    m_bottom = 0;
}

Rect::Rect(const Rect& nov)// конструктор копирования
{
    m_left = nov.m_left;
    m_right = nov.m_right;
    m_top = nov.m_top;
    m_bottom = nov.m_bottom;
    Sec();
}

Rect::~Rect()
{
    //std::cout << "Удаляем класс" << std::endl;
    //delete m_left;
}
```

В мейне создал экземпляры класса

```
    //Задание 5. Когда вызываются конструкторы и деструкторы.
    //Объявите и определите
    //явный деструктор класса. Поставьте остановы в 
    //конструкторе (конструкторах) и деструкторе. Определите: когда для
    //каждого из объектов вызывается конструктор, а когда - деструктор?
    {// вызывается конструктор без параметров r1 в прологе
        Rect r1;
        Rect*   pR = new Rect(1,2,1,2); //вызывается конструкторс с параметрами 
        {
            Rect r2(r1);// вызывается конструктор копирования 
            Rect arRect[2];//вызывактся по умолчанию
            for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                static Rect r3 (i,i,i,i) ;// конструктор вызывается при перво выполнении программы в прологе
                Rect r4(*pR); // вызывается конструктор копирования
                Rect r5(i,i,i,i);//вызывается конструкторс с параметрами 
            }// вызывается деструктор для r5,r4
        }// вызывается деструктор для r2,arRect

        delete pR;//вызывается деструктор для pR
        stop
    }//вызывается деструктор для  r1, r3
```

Comment: В деструкторе удаляется память, принадлежащая объекту класса, а не самого объекта класса. Создали `Rect* pR = new Rect(1,2,1,2);`? Потом просто удалите `delete pR;` — это удаление и вызовет деструктор. А в деструкторе удаляйте только то, что выделяли в конструкторе (в первом приближении, но пока вам хватит, потом разберетесь точнее).

Comment: Да. Всё верно. Я в main . cpp удалил delete pR; Просто у меня по заданию необходимо явно определить деструктор. Пустым я его оставить не могу, компилятор ругается. Пытался удалять переменные объявленные в классе, тоже не даёт. Как в этом случае явно объявить деструктор класса?

Comment: Как — не можете? Приведите-ка свой код...

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как сюда добвить код?

Comment: Добавил код в текст вопроса

Comment: Так а зачем вам деструктор? Вы никакую дополнительную память в конструкторе не выделяете. Но если нужен вроде можно пустой деструктор описывать, нет такого запрета. Покажите вашу ошибку.

Comment: В этом то и вопрос. Сам не пойму. Скорее всего в учебно-познавательных целях.

Comment: "Пустым я его оставить не могу, компилятор ругается." - покажите, как именно ругается компилятор! Возможно, это не ошибка, а предупреждение (типа того, что "пустой деструктор бесполезен"). Тогда можете это предупреждение просто игнорировать, раз вам такой деструктор нужен в учебных целях.

Comment: Да. Это предупреждение. Спасибо огромное)))). Просто уже в состоянии легкой паники.))) Всё работает

Comment: Деструктор вам по сути не нужен, так что или просто делаете пустой (как вы и сделали), либо просто пишете в кассе `~Rect() = default;` — что устраивает сгенерированный. На что у вас может ругаться компилятор в плане деструктора — не понимаю. Все вроде бы нормально. Что именно говорит компилятор?

Comment: Пишет, что не удалить класс Rect два раза.

Comment: Исправил на ~Rect() = default; перестал писать. Спасибо за подсказку!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам вообще не нужен ни деструктор, ни копирующий конструктор.

`new` и `delete` здесь тоже не нужны. Вместо `Rect* pR = new Rect(1,2,1,2);` пишите `Rect pR(1,2,1,2);`.

В комментариях предложили писать `~Rect() = default;` вместо отсутсвия деструктора, но это может создать проблемы (именно для этого класса не создаст, но все равно привычка плохая). Если вам достаточно пустого/`default` деструктора, то не надо писать деструктор вообще.

---

Почему плохо писать пустой деструктор просто так? Потому что если вы пишете любой деструктор, компилятор перестает генерировать перемещающий конструктор и оператор присваивания.

Это втихую заменит все перемещения вашего класса на копирования, если его вообще можно скопировать. Если скопировать нельзя, то класс перестанет быть перемещаемым. Пример:

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct A
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> p;

    // ~A() {}
    // ~A() = default;
};

int main()
{
    A x;
    A y = std::move(x);
}
```

Это компилируется. Если раскомментировать любой из деструкторов, перестает.

Чтобы этого не происходило, в дополнение к деструктору нужно объявить как `=default` перемещающие операции (и копирующие тоже, если они нужны, потому что иначе они пропадут из-за объявления перемещающих).

Comment: Каким бредовым языком вы все зачем-то пользуетесь

Comment: @avp В каком месте? И как бы вы написали?

Comment: Это я о С++ в целом. Вот из-за подобных засад в нем нельзя получить хороший софт (вы никогда не сможете набрать и *удержать* нужное количество программистов *достаточно высокого* уровня)

Comment: Из вопроса: *у меня по заданию необходимо явно определить деструктор*...

Comment: @avp А, вот вы про что. :) Да, меня эти мысли тоже не покидают. Здесь хотя бы радует, что это deprecated поведение (в смысле, тот факт, что создание деструктора пока еще не удаляет копирующие операции тоже). Когда оно из deprecated станет ошибкой, то это перестанет создавать проблемы, потому что будет сразу заметно.

Comment: @Harry Ну, раз надо, пусть определяет. Зато будет знать, как правильно.